# Android custom layout listview with images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I would like to manage to obtain a listview with dynamic items.
I built a row_layout containing an ImageView, and 2 TextViews.
When I build the adapter, I want to be able to display the ImageView OR NOT depending on the row number.
So I want to have img1 on row 2, img2 on row 3, then img3 on row 5. And on all other rows I do not want any imageView displayed (and also the alignment of the textviews must change filling the empty space left by the ImageView missing).

Is that possible?

I populate my adapter here:

```
JSONObject json_data;
try {
   int length = lststat.length();
   detalii_client = new Client[length];
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     json_data = lststat.getJSONObject(i);
     detalii_client[i] = new Client();
     String categoria = json_data.getString("den");
     if ("1".equals(categoria)){ // row 1
        detalii_client[i].desc ="Some Title";
        detalii_client[i].icon = 0; // here I want NO IMAGE
     }
     if ("2".equals(categoria)){ // row 2
        detalii_client[i].desc ="Some other Title";
        detalii_client[i].icon = 0; // here I want to assign a picture to the imageView
     }
....
```

I have a class:

```
public class Client {
    public int icon;
            public String desc;
            public String title;
            public String id;
            public Client(){
                super();
            }

            public Client(int icon, String desc, String title, String id) {
                super();
                this.icon = icon;
                this.desc = desc;
                this.id = id;
                this.title= title;
            }
    }
```

and a custom Adapter class

```
public class ClientAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Client>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Client data[] = null;

    public ClientAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Client[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ClientHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ClientHolder();
            holder.hldIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIconx);
            holder.hldTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitlu);
            holder.hldDesc = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescr);
            holder.hldId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ClientHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Client clientul = data[position];
        holder.hldTitle.setText(clientul.title);
        holder.hldDesc.setText(clientul.desc);
        holder.hldId.setText(clientul.id);
        holder.hldIcon.setImageResource(clientul.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class ClientHolder
    {
        ImageView hldIcon;
        TextView hldTitle;
        TextView hldId;
        TextView hldDesc;
    }    
}
```

Also I have an activity layout (irrelevant) One listview and a bottom button (relativeLayout).
And I have a row_layout which I use to display the rows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIconx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/client64" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lbl_loc"
                android:textColor="@color/darkred"
                android:textSize="@dimen/descriere_detaliu"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lbl_client"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/darkred"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lbl_idviz"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- Where can I assign my pictures to my ImageView?
- And How can I make the ImageView "disappear" for certain rows?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I assign my pictures to my ImageView?

Do this in the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`. It looks like you are doing that now.

> And How can I make the ImageView "disappear" for certain rows?

Use an`if` statement and `if` it isn't the correct row (`position`) call

```
holder.hldIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`
```

or

```
holder.hldIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

depending on what you want

Comment: 1. if I set visibility... then the image does not show, but the row remains aligned just like the rest of the rows. I mean the TextViews look like in the rows where there is Image

Comment: If you change it to `invisible` it will still take up the same space. If you use `gone` then it will be removed and the space will be used by the other `Views`

Comment: 2. I read about getview and tried to do it in my code but I have no idea on how to assign different images to different rows. I added to assets folder, an images folder where I added my 3-4 pictures (png). But how to assign the pictures to the ImageView?

Comment: You were right about View.GONE. It does exactly what I needed. The issue remains with Loading the image from assets folder... Can you help?

Comment: I mean... I added to my above code the following: `switch (position){
             case 0:holder.hldIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             case 1:{
              int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("gmaps64", "drawable",  context.getPackageName());
iw.setImageResource(resID);              
             }}` and I have a png file located in the res/drawable-mdpi folder named gmaps64.png But no image gets rendered. Even more... it looks like View.GONE for row 1 too even if I did not call that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `holder.hldIcon.setImageResource(resID);` to set the image?

Comment: It does not work like this either... Might it be that I did not place the picture where it should be? Or maybe `resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("gmaps64", "drawable", context.getPackageName());` has wrong arguments?

Comment: If the image is in the `res/drawable` then you can use `resID = getResources().getDrawable(imageID);`

Comment: This way I obtain a drawable not an Int inside resID... :( And I do not know the IDs of the images... How do I know which image has which ID?

Comment: You set it in your xml. `R.id.your_drawable_name`. Its the name of your file without the xml extension...just like a layout file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34576/discussion-between-user1137313-and-codemagic)

Comment: When you say "drawable folder", do you mean the gen/R.java/drawable folder? I checked it... I have the gmaps64 in there. I can see it if I do R.drawable. (it shows all my drawables in the autocomplete). So it exists... so why doesn't it work? Is it because in my row_layout in the ImageView I have set a default image with rightClick? Is that the problem? The symptom is that when I run the app, I either have the image preset on designtime, or I have no image at the positions where I set View.GONE.

Comment: But the parts where I assign other drawables are simply ignored. I see no error, but it's like I did not write them

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your help. You were of great help for me. Too many hours of work today for me (early morning already for me). I must take a break. Have a nice evening there.