# How to add blocks of linearLayouts and is there a better way?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

[image]

This is the main idea of what I am trying to do.
I would like to ask you what is the best way to make such a design. the problem is that these gray/black blocks might not show up (user will choose which should show up). So I would like to find out do I need to make these 3 text views inside linearLayout programatically? Is there anyway to create some sort of template which I would only have to edit by setting new texts for textViews and add them to some sort of layout?

Comment: I would create them with the blocks, use a `ListView` and in `getView()` determine if the blocks need to show or not and toggle the `Visibility`

Comment: @codeMagic awesome! Didn't know you can do that. Going to try to figure this out now. Maybe you can recommend some tutorial for this?

Comment: [Section 3 here](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html&sa=U&ei=44bqUrKRLs3O2QWE6IDoDw&ved=0CAYQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNG-UUJRD1iS4Kke7r8sP4PYrS07Jg) should be a good one for custom `Adapter` on `ListView`

Comment: And [this answer may help with visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982735/android-custom-layout-listview-with-images/17982856#17982856)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to just have a `LinearLayout` and an `xml` for the row entry. Then you can do:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
List<Blocks> userBlocks = getMyUserBlocks();
for(Block b : userBlocks) {
    View blockView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, layout, false);
    TextView someData = (TextView) blockView.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
    someData.setText(b.someAttribute.toString());
    layout.addView(blockView);
}
```

You will need a separate xml layout for the block row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView with large dividers. Your dark gray blocks are the row views, and you can just append them to a dataset and update the adapter for the ListView. For the dividers, see [`setDivider()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and [`setDividerHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight%28int%29).